# Xamarin MasterPage Concept

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Good evening!

I'm starting with Xamarin, I wonder what "tool" should I use to create a layout using the concept of masterpage, the idea is to have a fixed side menu with some buttons, each button will display a content at the center of the screen, I'm studying Fragments.
Using fragments in my project would be a good choice?
Is there any easier way to do this?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements are exactly, but one way to do this is to use MasterDetailPage from Xamarin Forms (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/). It should be very simple to implement that way.

However, if your preference is to not stray away from 100% Xamarin.Android features, then that wouldn't be helpful.